# Allow user to see how many iptables rules are loaded, but not actual contents?

Tags: sudo, iptables

I want to allow user to check how many rules are present in filter table, but not able to view  actual rules, is that possible?

literally I mean `iptables -L | wc -l` (I know it's faulty), but sudo doesn't seem to support pipe commands like that, I mean, currently If I wanted to allow that, I need to grant permission to run `iptables -L` instead of `iptables -L | wc -l`

Any thoughts?

Comment: not sure what shell you are using but I'am able to run the following:
sudo iptables -L|egrep -v 'Chain|target'|wc -l without any problem

Comment: @AlexandreAlves updated question ...

Comment: The reason that pipe commands do not work with sudo, is because it is actually two separate commands...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a script that runs the commands to get the number of iptables rules. I would suggest something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iptables -L | grep -Ecv '^$|^Chain |^target'
```

Save script in /usr/local/bin, make it executable and check that only root can write to it. Recommended mode: 0555

Edit `sudoers` to allow the user to run that script using sudo.

Comment: Looks easy to do that! But anyway, I modified iptables program to do the counting ... thanks anyway, scripting is a good ideas to problems like this

Comment: (This is not completely valid with the edited case where the user doesn't have permissions to run `iptables -L`) (the info seem to require root to access, so a modified `iptables` (or other command getting the info from `/proc/net/ip_*`) running setuid root or via `sudo` is likely the only practical solution)